# Can we decompose the likelihood function of a composite model into the likelihoods of of its parts?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Let's say we have some models $f,f'$ with parameters $\theta_f$ and $\theta_f'$. Can we generally express the conditional likelihood function of $f' \circ f$ in terms of the likelihoods of $f$ and $f'$? That is, is there some function $g$ such that we can write the following?
\begin{align*}
L_{f' \circ f} = g(L_{f}, L_{f'})
\end{align*}
Perhaps there is some measure $\mu$ for which we can write something like the following for a single data sample?
\begin{align*}
    L_{f' \circ f}(a,c, \theta_1 \oplus \theta_2) = \int_b L_f(a,b, \theta_1)L_{f'}(b,c,\theta_2) d\mu
\end{align*}
For example, $f$ and $f'$ might be linear regression models, in which case:
\begin{align*}
    f(a) = \beta_1 a + \beta_0\\
    f'(b) = \beta_1' b + \beta_0'\\
    (f' \circ f)(a) = \beta_1'(\beta_1 a + \beta_0) + \beta_0'
\end{align*}
In this case I believe that the likelihood functions of these models for a single data sample would be:
\begin{align*}
    L_{f}(a,b) = \mathcal{N}(b - \beta_1 a - \beta_0, \sigma)\\
    L_{f'}(b,c) = \mathcal{N}(c - \beta_1' b - \beta_0', \sigma')\\
    L_{f' \circ f}(a,c) = \mathcal{N}(c - \beta_1'\beta_1 a + \beta_1' \beta_0 + \beta_0', \beta_0'\sigma + \sigma')
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I have figured this out. I believe our goal is to express the conditional likelihood function:
\begin{align*}
P(c | a,\theta_1,\theta_2) = L_{f'\circ f}(a,c,\theta_1 \oplus \theta_2)
\end{align*}
In terms of:
\begin{align*}
P(b | a,\theta_1) = L_{f}(a,b, \theta_1)\\
P(c | b,\theta_2) = L_{f'}(b,c, \theta_2)
\end{align*}
We can see that:
\begin{align*}
    P(c | a,b,\theta_1,\theta_2) = P(c | b,\theta_2)\\
    P(b | a,\theta_1,\theta_2) = P(b | a,\theta_1)
\end{align*}
So by Bayes rule we can write:
\begin{align*}
    \frac{P(b,c | a,\theta_1,\theta_2)}{P(b | a,\theta_1,\theta_2)} = P(c | b,a,\theta_1,\theta_2)\\
    P(b,c | a,\theta_1,\theta_2) = P(c | b,a,\theta_1,\theta_2)P(b | a,\theta_1,\theta_2)\\
    P(b,c | a,\theta_1,\theta_2) = P(c | b,\theta_2)P(b | a,\theta_1)\\
    \int_b P(b,c | a,\theta_1,\theta_2) db = \int_b P(c | b,\theta_2)P(b | a,\theta_1) db \\
    P(c | a,\theta_1,\theta_2) = \int_b P(c | b,\theta_2)P(b | a,\theta_1) db 
\end{align*}